# Why does the Frobenius-semisimplicity of a Weil representation not depend on the choice of the Frobenius element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

**Definition**: Let $K$ be a (non-Archimedean) local field and $k$ its residue field.

- A **Frobenius element** of the absolute Galois group $G_K$ is any element of $G_K$ which is a lift of the Frobenius automorphism $x \mapsto x^{|k|}$ in $G_k \simeq G_K/I_K$.
- A Weil representation $\rho$ is called **Frobenius-semisimple** if $\rho(\Phi)$ is diagonalizable for some Frobenius element $\Phi$ in $G_K$.

**Question**: If $\rho$ is a Frobenius-semisimple Weil representation why is $\rho(\Phi')$ diagonalizable for any Frobenius element $\Phi'$ in $G_K$?

**Attempts**:

- I know that the Frobenius element in $G_K$ is unique up to an element in $I_K$, i.e. if $\Phi, \Phi'$ are two Frobenius elements in $G_K$, there exists an element $\sigma \in I_K$ with $\Phi' = \Phi \circ \sigma$.
- Let us say that $\rho(\Phi')$ is diagonalizable and $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is a basis of the representation space consisting of eigenvectors of $\rho(\Phi')$. The only thing I was able to show with that $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is also a basis of eigenvectors of $\rho(\sigma^{-1}\circ \Phi \circ \sigma)$. But this is not helpful since I want to find a basis of eigenvectors for $\Phi$.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You probably want to use that fact that $\rho$ is continuous, so that $\rho(I_K)$ is finite. It turns out for a Weil representation, Frobenius-semisimple is the same as just being semisimple. The notions become different when you consider Weil-Deligne representations.

Comment: @Mathmo123: Thanks for your remark! It is$\rho(I_K)$ is finite, so let $\rho(\sigma_1), \dots \rho(\sigma_m)$ for $\sigma_i \in I_K$ be these elements. Then the image of a Frobenius element must be one of the values $\rho(\Phi \circ \sigma_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,m$. Could this be helpful? I have problems to see how this can lead to the semisimplicity.

Comment: Representations of finite groups are always semi-simple (in characteristic zero).